# Is it possible to add a column of distinct/unique values to a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently using Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.

A client has requested a report that shows the sales value and profit for specific customers with a column that shows every item that each customer has purchased as a unique value. The unique/distinct column should not alter the initial query.

This is what I have so far:

```
select  
    cus_code as "Customer Account No.",
    cus_name as "Customer Name",
    sum(cmoh_value) as "Sales Value",
    sum(cmoh_cost_value) as "Cost Value",
    sum(cmoh_value-cmoh_cost_value) as "G.P. Value",
    round(sum(cmoh_value-cmoh_cost_value) / sum(cmoh_value)*100,2) as "G.P. %"
from completed_order_header
inner join completed_order_line on cmoh_company_number=cmol_company_number and cmoh_branch_number=cmol_branch_number and cmoh_order_number=cmol_order_number
inner join customer_master on cmoh_company_number=cus_company and cmoh_customer=cus_code
where cmoh_company_number = 1
  and cmoh_branch_number = 1
  and cmoh_status <> 3
  and cmoh_desp_date between '01-JAN-20' and '31-DEC-20'
  and cmoh_value <> 0
group by cus_code, cus_name
order by cus_code, cus_name
;
```

So now I want to add a column at the end for the sales item:

```
select distinct
    cus_code,
    cus_name,
    cmol_item_code
from completed_order_header
inner join completed_order_line on cmoh_company_number=cmol_company_number and cmoh_branch_number=cmol_branch_number and cmoh_order_number=cmol_order_number
inner join customer_master on cmoh_company_number=cus_company and cmoh_customer=cus_code
where cmoh_company_number = 1
  and cmoh_branch_number = 1
  and cmoh_status <> 3
  and cmoh_desp_date between '01-JAN-20' and '31-DEC-20'
  and cmoh_value <> 0
  and cmol_item_code not in ('TEXT')
order by cus_code, cus_name
;
```

I *think* this script will return the unique items that have been purchased by each customer and I'd like that list of items as a column in the original query. I can just run each query individually and use the data to create the report the client is asking for, but as I'd like to improve my SQL skills, I'm curious about how this can be done as a single script.

EDIT:

Using LISTAGG as suggested returns error, script used:

```
select  
    cus_code as "Customer Account No.",
    cus_name as "Customer Name",
    sum(cmoh_value) as "Sales Value",
    sum(cmoh_cost_value) as "Cost Value",
    sum(cmoh_value-cmoh_cost_value) as "G.P. Value",
    round(sum(cmoh_value-cmoh_cost_value) / sum(cmoh_value)*100,2) as "G.P. %",
    listagg(cmol_item_code, ',') within group (order by cus_code, cus_name) as Items
from completed_order_header
inner join completed_order_line on cmoh_company_number=cmol_company_number and cmoh_branch_number=cmol_branch_number and cmoh_order_number=cmol_order_number
inner join customer_master on cmoh_company_number=cus_company and cmoh_customer=cus_code
where cmoh_company_number = 1
  and cmoh_branch_number = 1
  and cmoh_status <> 3
  and cmoh_desp_date between '01-JAN-20' and '31-DEC-20'
  and cmoh_value <> 0
group by cus_code, cus_name
order by cus_code, cus_name
;
```

Error Message Received:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 45
```

Comment: Your first query is not valid Oracle, so the question confuses me.  Do you need to fix the first query?  Do you have the wrong database tag?  Do you have additional information you want to include?

Comment: There was a typo that has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for `listagg`?

```
listagg(so_sales_item, ',') within group (order by so_sales_item) as so_sales_item
```

Comment: I receive the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" when using listagg.

Comment: Please share the query that you have used

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've updated the post and included my attempt at using LISTAGG if you have any thoughts